# cant set margin and padding to 0

Tags: css, margin, padding

im building a tic-tac-toe game and the board ive drawn with css keeps moving on my insert of an 'X' as if the 'X' has a margin property.  I've set all margin and padding to 0 or none and it moves my board every time one is inserted.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sq").click(function(){
        $(this).html("<em class='x'>X</em>");
    });
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="gameboard">
            <div class="sq" id="top-left"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="top-mid"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="top-right"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="mid-left"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="mid-mid"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="mid-right"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="bot-left"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="bot-mid"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="bot-right"></div>
    </div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

heres the css file:

```
div {
    position: static;
}

#gameboard {
    width: 900px;
}

#top-left {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#top-mid {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#top-right {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#mid-left {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#mid-mid {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#mid-right {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#bot-left {

    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#bot-mid {

    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#bot-right {

}

.sq {
    padding: none;
    margin: -5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}

.x {
    padding: 0;
    margin: none;
    font-size: 150px;
}

.o {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `position:absolute` to `<em>` element (in this case `x`);

```css
div {
    position: static;
}

#gameboard {
    width: 900px;
}

#top-left {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#top-mid {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#top-right {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#mid-left {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#mid-mid {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#mid-right {

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#bot-left {

    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#bot-mid {

    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#bot-right {

}

.sq {
    padding: none;
    margin: -5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}

.x {
    padding: 0;
    margin: none;
    font-size: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

.o {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sq").click(function(){
        $(this).html("<em class='x'>X</em>");
    });
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="gameboard">
            <div class="sq" id="top-left"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="top-mid"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="top-right"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="mid-left"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="mid-mid"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="mid-right"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="bot-left"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="bot-mid"></div>
            <div class="sq" id="bot-right"></div>
    </div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I close a question??